# Why do I get "undefined method 'insertsaying' for main:Object"?

Tags: ruby, methods, datamapper

I'm using DataMapper to create rows in MySQL. To make a new row in my "Ryne" table, I do:

```
a = {:saying, "Ppffftt..!"}
Ryne.create a
```

So I said to myself, "Since I use this all the time, why not make a more 'slick' method which does this...":

```
def insertsaying(x)
    h = {:saying, x}
    Ryne.create h 
end
```

However, my output in IRB for `insert saying("Pffffft..")` is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `insertsaying' for main:Object
from (irb):2
```

The method itself is defined in a .rb file which I am currently requiring in IRB. Aside from the `DataMapper.setup` call, the rest of the .rb file looks like this:

```
DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
dm = DataMapper.setup :default, "mysql://php:phpwebsite@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/visit"
dm.resource_naming_convention = DataMapper::NamingConventions::Resource::Underscored


class Ryne
    include DataMapper::Resource
    is :reflective
    reflect /.*/
end

DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

def insertsaying(x)
    h = {:saying, x}
    Ryne.create h 
end
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong however I believe it is a scope issue. Do I need to require something else in the method?

Comment: Are you doing all this in IRB? Is method defined also in IRB?

Comment: No the method is defined in a .rb script I require which includes the table mapping and DataMapper.setup calls.

Comment: I updated the original question to show the rest of the .rb file for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote `{:saying, x}` correct?

Comment: don't make naked functions like that. Wrap them in a class. Ruby is pro-OO language :)

Comment: More or less what I'm wanting to know is why I'm getting the undefined method error...I thought that naked methods or functions are defined under class Object.

Comment: They are defined in Object, but I think @SergioTulentsev is telling you to move `insertsaying` inside `Ryne`, because that is where it should be logically.

Comment: Thanks, @theTinMan, that was my point.